# readstream error RangeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'size' is invalid. Received 32212254720

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, fs

I am trying to `createReadStream` and concat into as `Buffer`, following by feeding into aws-sdk to do a multipart upload to S3 Glacier, however I faced the error with a large filesize, any size > 30GB - 2.5TB.

```
RangeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'size' is invalid. Received 32212254720
    at Function.allocUnsafe (node:buffer:373:3)
    at Function.concat (node:buffer:552:25)
```

My code

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const path = require("path");
var fs = require('fs');

// var buffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

const readFile = async (path) => {
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(path);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const bufferParts = [];

        stream.on('data', (data) => {
            bufferParts.push(data);
        });

        stream.on('end', () => {
            resolve(Buffer.concat(bufferParts))
        });
    })
}

async function uploadToAws() {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'sample.txt');
    // Create a new service object and some supporting variables
    var glacier = new AWS.Glacier({ apiVersion: '2012-06-01', region: 'ap-southeast-1' }),
        vaultName = '{vaultName}',
        buffer = await readFile(filePath),
        partSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, // 4GB chunks,
        numPartsLeft = Math.ceil(buffer.length / partSize),
        startTime = new Date(),
        params = { vaultName: vaultName, partSize: partSize.toString() };
.
.
.
```

I searched a bit and seems that it's due to Js limitation. I changed from `readFileSync` to `createReadStream` due to big file size used. but error still occurs
What could be the cause of this? how do i resolve this?

thanks